# Questions with "Interview:" in the Title on StackOverflow

Tags: discussion, questions, title

I'm seeing [questions with "Interview:" in the title](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=title:Interview) in some fashion or another.  Do we take that stuff out the same way we do with Tags?

Comment: On which Stack Exchange site, specifically?

Comment: @Oded http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=title%3A%22Interview%3A%22

Comment: Meh, that's a big collection of bad titles (and possibly bad questions)

Comment: @Oded Dang...I'm too old I keep forgetting about SE!

Comment: Heh. Point was that sites like The Workplace & Freelancing may very well be OK with such titles. On [so] and Programmers, however, chances are that the question itself is off-topic.

Comment: @Yannis wow...didn't even think about doing that with the link!